# Workaround for unrecognized <section> tags in older browsers

Tags: html

I have a pair of nested section tags to set the width of my content, but am having problems with browsers (or versions of browsers) that don't recognize the  tag: they're just allowing the content to fill the entire width of the parent container.

My code looks essentially like this:

```
<body>
    <section style="min-width:800px">
        <section style="width:500px">
            <p>Bunch of Text Here That Forms The Content</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Now in browsers that don't recognize the `<section`> tag, the content in the inner `<section`> behaves as if the tag does not exist, and the content simply fills the width of the page. Any idea what I can do about it?

Comment: have you tried http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/ ? The article tells pretty everything you need to know.

Comment: No I did not run into this. Thanks, let me read this through :)

Comment: Um, this deals with IE, but not other browsers, such as older Firefox versions. Will the script work on those as well?

Comment: that's why its not an answer, just a comment. Its to point you in the right direction. But the problem is basically the same in other browsers...

Comment: @meo: “the problem is basically the same in other browsers” — it’s not really in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind your site's design and layout **depending on JavaScript for older browsers** (mainly IE versions 6-8), you can use the [HTML5 JavaScript shim for IE](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stack Overflow Rocks!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/file.css" media="all" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

To use this script, it must be included before the  element (i.e. in the `<head>`) but doesn't matter if it appears before or after any CSS. However, for the sake of performance, it's preferable to include any CSS before this script.

A clever and somewhat creative approach that *doesn't rely on JavaScript* is to insert an element that IE/Win 6-8 understands, (such as a plain old `<div>`) inside of the semantic HTML5 elements:

```
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Business as Usual Here -->
        ...
    </div>
</aside>
```

You can then apply your CSS using either the ID (for older browsers) or the HTML5 element (for modern browsers):

```
aside,
#sidebar {
    ...
}
```

While this approach adds an extra set of tags for each HTML5 element — *and arguably isn't a pure as the native HTML5 method* — it doesn't depend on JavaScript and **your site's layout can look the same with or without JavaScript enabled**.

---

*For further reading about HTML5 elements and IE/Win, see [The Story of the HTML5 Shiv](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/).*

Comment: oh, that’s a good shout. One could (if one was being really finicky) use conditional comments for the extra HTML elements so that they only get served to IE.

Comment: Oh this is seriously nice. Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers treat unknown tags as if they had `display: inline` applied to them. You’ll want to apply `display: block` to `<section>` (and other block-level HTML5 tags, if you plan to use them) in your stylesheet. (Reset stylesheets, like [Eric Meyer’s](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), often take care of this for you.)

Older versions of IE, in contrast, won’t allow you to style tags at all if they don’t know about them (e.g. IE 6 was not aware of the `<abbr>` tag even though it was in the HTML 4 spec), unless you create that an instance of the tag via JavaScript. That’s what the [HTML5 shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv) does.