# Why does html5lib sanitizer remove <section> tags?

Tags: django, html, python-2.7, django-cms, html5lib

I am just trying to figure this out. Inside the sanitizer code of html5lib, `<section>` is not listed as an acceptable element. Why?

The only [reason](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/) I have been able to figure out is that it is not supported by IE 6-8.

Is there some way I can force the issue without having to modify html5lib code? Or should I just figure out a workaround? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499153/workaround-for-unrecognized-section-tags-in-older-browsers) mentions using an `<aside>` tag and a `<div>` tag. Personally this stinks of inelegance to me, I would rather use `<section>` and possibly use the HTML5 Shiv JavaScript library to make it work in older, non-standards compliant browsers.

Of course, I could always modify the library, but I wanted to know if there is a deeper reason for the absence.

Answer (score 1):

> Inside the sanitizer code of html5lib,  is not listed as an
>   acceptable element.

[That's clearly not true.](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/blob/master/html5lib/sanitizer.py) Maybe you are using a really old version?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/commit/5d493a5a3a5e7d24703ec7d9887d819c2da6ce5f) commit appears to introduce it — so it's shipped in 0.95 and above.